# Multiple rows to Columns (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

i am currently working in a database that has a table that looks like this:

```
ID    | Type   | Value
11111 | Type1 | 45
11111 | Type2 | 85
11111 | Type3 | 26
11111 | Type4 | 69
11112 | Type1 | 14
11112 | Type2 | 36
11113 | Type1 | 69
11113 | Type3 | 25
```

This table works as followed:

Each ID appears multiple times in the table. 
Each ID has one or more types. 
Each type has a value

In the example above you can see that the ID 11112 does not have a Type3 or a Type4 and that ID 11113 does not have a Type2 or Type4.

The problem with this is that some of these types (with the corresponding value) should be there for every ID, to make this happen a list should be created with all the ID's that are missing one or more of these types. This is so that it's easy to see what id's need their type and value added.

Is there a query that can make such a list? One that gives the Unique ID's of every instance that is missing one or more types? I was able to get the ID with only a specific type missing, but i have not been able to make it so that the ID is listed of any type is missing.

Comment: "every ID should have every type (with the corresponding value)" - what is a "corresponding value"? For ID = 11111, Type3, Value = **26**. But, for ID = 11113, Type3 has value **25**. So, which value should you create for ID = 11112 Type3 (which is missing)? 25 or 26? Or some other value?

Comment: The value is based on a real life measurment that belongs to that ID/type combination. So it can be any number and needs to be put in by hand. Thats why a list of the missing types is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate all required types and id combinations and then filter out the ones that exist:

```
with required_types as (
      select 'type3' as type from dual union all
      select 'type4' as type from dual
     )
select i.id, rt.type
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     required_types rt left join
     t
     on t.id = i.id and t.type = rt.type
where t.id is null;
```

If all types present in the data are required, you can use `(select distinct type from t)`.

Answer (score 0):

This query shows all ID's where at least one type is missing:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM T
GROUP BY ID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TYPE)<(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TYPE) FROM T)
```

Comment: I'm afraid i formulated my question wrong. I eddited now. Not every ID should have every type, but some types should be there for every ID. My apologies for the mistake.

Comment: @A.Bakker you haven't told us what the rules are; how do we know which types should be there for every id, and which shouldn't?

Comment: There are over 70 types, and a dozen or 2 that should be there for every ID.  I simplified it to keep the post a bit more readable. If there is a working example that can show a list where 3 types are handled (as in the ID is on the query result if one or more of those 3 are missing) i could manually add the others that are required

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but will return IDs and types they are missing. I removed superfluous "1111" from IDs and "ype" from types (was too lazy to type them all).

```
SQL> with test (id, type) as
  2    (select 1, 't1' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 't2' from dual union all
  4     select 1, 't3' from dual union all
  5     select 1, 't4' from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 2, 't1' from dual union all
  8     select 2, 't2' from dual union all
  9     --
 10     select 3, 't1' from dual union all
 11     select 3, 't3' from dual
 12    ),
 13  all_types as
 14    (select distinct type from test)
 15  --
 16  select t.id, a.type
 17  from test t join all_types a on 1 = 1
 18  minus
 19  select t.id, t.type
 20  from test t;

        ID TY
---------- --
         2 t3
         2 t4
         3 t2
         3 t4

SQL>
```

Comment: Elegance is not an issue, but from what i see on a first glance of this query is that the select process has to be done for every ID and every mandatory type?         Because the problem would be that there are thousands of id's and dozens of types.

Comment: That's what you asked for, didn't you?